# Attaching WCF DLL to existing Website

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

Okay I've created a WCF which I have tested in in IIS and works correctly.

There is a website running, and I've done the following to add this service to that domain:

-Copied the WCF DLL into the website's bin folder.

-Also copied all the DLL this service uses. (Just Newtonsoft.Json)

-Created a new .svc with the following line:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="wcfOnScore.OnScoreQuery"%>
```

-And also added the following to the website's web.config file:

```
<System.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WithDebug">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
</protocolMapping>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" />
<services>
  <service name="wcfOnScore.OnScoreQuery">
      <endpoint address="http://www.onscore.co.za/OnScoreQuery.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
                listenUri="/"
              contract="wcfOnScore.IOnScoreQuery" />
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Now this seems to be working. I get the following page when I open it in the browser:**

[image: Screenshot of ServicePage]

[Link To The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7zOZ.png)

It is however, not working sadly. I am trying to consume this service from a c# Xamarin android application. It is supposed to return a JSON string. **And does this fine when it is hosted locally - This leads me to believe the problem is not in the WCF but the way I am trying to host it.**

Anything I might have missed? Or any other alternatives?

Thanks in advance people.

**EDIT:**

Thought I'd include the error.

"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

The is what the completed eventhandler arguments returns.

Comment: Sounds like an exception thrown from your code.  I suggest you enable WCF tracing (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) which should give you more details of the exception - in particular the InnerException and its stack trace.

Comment: It is not the case. I've tested locally. And also tested a version of the DLL that only does a test string return. So I believe the code to be correct.

Comment: you still need to look at the InnerException of your TargetInvocationException if you want to understand what's happening.

Comment: Well you were right! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well this an answer to why I get the error, not really a solution. (Yet)

I commented out the Newtonsof.Json using statement. And put in a simple text return which worked.

So from this I deduce that the WCF code can't get its hands on the json.dll.

So it looks like all the above was done correctly if you would like to use as reference. (Except that .dll off course).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to return JSON first test it on browser. Your service is SOAP based service because you are using `basicHttpBinding`. To get result on browser change the binding to `WebHttpBinding` and add following in your web config.

```
<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RestBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
```

If you are able to get response on the browser, you will get response through android also.

Comment: I got it to return a string to my Android App. I have isolated the problem to the fact that the service code can't find the newtonsoft.json.dll. I need to reference it correctly. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29254296/adding-a-dll-reference-to-a-project-without-visual-studio) out if you have time? Thanks